# Check For File Update In Server Without Refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Here is what I am trying to do:

- I want to read a file that has a number
- I want to add one to that number, display it on the page, AND store it back to the original file
- I want to be able to do this over and over without refreshing the page.

I have it figured out where I can do this, but only once. Once I hit a button, it adds one and displays the number, then stores it to the file, but I have to refresh to do it again. I have never used AJAX before so I'm wondering if this is even possible to do. In the most basic terms I want to be able to press a button and read a file that is constantly changing. Can it be done?

Comment: Use jquery ajax. Read doc here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Can it be done? Yes.

Comment: Yes it can be done just by adding an event handler(function) on the click of a button and you will have to make an ajax request to your same previous code